# Firebase upload function works differently everytime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a form to upload a new item, that has a few fields and an image.
The way I've built the function is that it first sets the new document in Firestore, then it uploads the image, and then it resets the form.

The problem is that it doesn't always work. Sometimes the image gets uploaded and sometimes it isn't even if the form was reset (the reset is conditioned with the image upload).

It's not consistent so I can't figure out what exactly is happening.

This is the upload function:

```
export const newItem = (values, image, setValues) => () => {
  const newDoc = db.collection("items").doc();

  newDoc.set({ ...values, id: newDoc.id }).then(() => {
    storageRef
      .child(`images/items/${newDoc.id}`)
      .put(image)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        setValues({});
      });
  });
};
```

I call it is as follows:

```
newItem({ ...values, is_public }, imageObj, setValues);
```

Then I have this cloud function that addes the url for the newly uploaded file to the new document (but I don't think the issue is there, because when I say the image wasn't uploaded, then I mean I don't even see it in storage):

```
exports.writeFileToDatabase = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(object => {
  const bucket = defaultStorage.bucket();
  const path = object.name as string;
  const file = bucket.file(path);

  return file
    .getSignedUrl({
      action: "read",
      expires: "03-17-2025"
    })
    .then(results => {
      const url = results[0];
      const silcedPath = path.split("/", 3);

      switch (silcedPath[1]) {
        case "user-avatars":
          return db
            .collection("users")
            .doc(silcedPath[2])
            .set({ avatar: url }, { merge: true });

        case "items":
          return db
            .collection("items")
            .doc(silcedPath[2])
            .set({ image: url }, { merge: true });

        default:
          return null;
      }
    });
});
```

EDIT:

this is how I choose the file:

```
  <input
    id="image"
    className="new-item__upload"
    type="file"
    onChange={handleImageChange}
  />
```

Then this is `handleImageChange`:

```
  const handleImageChange = e => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      const image = e.target.files[0];
      setSelectedImage(URL.createObjectURL(image));
      setImageObj(image); // This is what end up being given to the function to upload
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you add, in your `newItem` function, a [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method call at the end of your Promises chain, in order to get more details on the error. What do you get when the upload does not work?

Comment: @RenaudTarnecI have and it just kept refreshing. I've removed the `setValues` call, and so far it seems to be working consistently (though I still haven't used it enough to say for certain). But I don't understand. setValues is only called after the image has been uploaded, so why would this affect it?

Comment: Have a look at the answer: you need to correctly chain the promises returned by the asynchronous operations, by using the `then()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly [chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) the promises returned by the Firebase asynchronous operations (`set()` and `put()`) as follows:

```
export const newItem = (values, image, setValues) => () => {
  const newDoc = db.collection("items").doc();

  newDoc.set({ ...values, id: newDoc.id })
   .then(() => {
     return storageRef         //Here return the Promise returned by the put() method
      .child(`images/items/${newDoc.id}`)
      .put(image);
   })
   .then(snapshot => {   
       console.log(snapshot);
       setValues({});
   })
   .catch(e => {
      console.error(e.message); 
      //You should throw an error here, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling
   });

};
```

It is also recommended to add a [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method call at the end of your Promises chain, in order to get more details in case of error.

Comment: That didn't work, but when I removed the `return` it did. Still checking to see how stable it is

Comment: What exactly is the `image` Object? It should be a valid object in the light of the following doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files

Comment: It's just a regular jpeg. When it uploads then it uploads just fine

Comment: I just had it fail. So inconsistent.

Comment: Ok, but what is the error? I've never experienced any inconsistency when uploading files. Are you on a slow internet connection?

Comment: "It's just a regular jpeg. " -> Is your Object a JavaScript file? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: I've added my file choice function. So am I doing it wrong?

Comment: It seems ok. You need to pass `e.target.files[0]` to `put()`. But, again, do you get an error in the `catch` block?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I can't get it to fail at this point! Maybe it is stable, I'll write back if it end up failing again